# What is causing the name error fault in my linkedlist queue python file from working

Tags: python, linked-list, queue

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.technotification.com/2018/09/queue-using-linked-list-in-python.html)(mplementing Queue Using a Linked List in Python Programming),  for creating a linkedlist queue and I am finding that when I attempt to run the code I am getting a name error fault that says that the enqueue function is not defined.

```
# queue is empty at beginning

queue = {'front': None, 'back': None}

# we will use a node to keep track of the elements
# in the queue which is represented by a linked list

class node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

# add elements to queue in 0(1) time
    def enqueue(queue, element):
        N = node(element, None)
        if queue['back'] == None:
            queue['front'] = N
            queue['back'] = N
        else:
            queue['back'].next = N
            queue['back'] = queue['back'].next

# remove first element from queue in 0(1) time
def dequeue(queue):
    if queue['front'] != None:

        first = queue['front']
        queue['front'] = queue['front'].next
        return first.data
    else:
        if queue['back'] != None:
            queue['back'] = None
        return 'Cannot dequeue because queue isempty'

enqueue(queue, 'a')
enqueue(queue, 'b')
enqueue(queue, 'c')

print (dequeue(queue))
```

Comment: Hi there, can you add the full error or traceback you're getting? Thanks.

Comment: what tutorial? your question is not well formated. please change the format so we can try to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong. Right now `enqueue(queue, element)` is a class method of `class node`.

Try shifting it to the left:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

# add elements to queue in 0(1) time
def enqueue(queue, element):
    N = node(element, None)
    if queue['back'] == None:
        queue['front'] = N
        queue['back'] = N
    else:
        queue['back'].next = N
        queue['back'] = queue['back'].next
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: if it solved your problem you can mark the question as solved